Why does a binary produced by graalvm's native-image try to load libc.so.6 on macOS?
Does anyone have a clue why a binary produced by native-image on macOS would try to load libc.so.6 when ran... and not, say, libc.dylib or something similar...? Might someone have ideas on how to fix the below?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base@22.0.1/jdk.internal.foreign.SystemLookup.find(SystemLookup.java:43)
    at testlib.NativeBridge.ffi(NativeBridge.java:16)
    at testlib.core$run_app.invokeStatic(core.clj:11)
    at testlib.core$run_app.invoke(core.clj:7)
    at testlib.kitchen_sink.main$_main.invokeStatic(main.clj:10)
    at testlib.kitchen_sink.main$_main.invoke(main.clj:8)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at testlib.kitchen_sink.main.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base@22.0.1/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't load library: libc.so.6
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.foreign/com.oracle.svm.core.foreign.Util_java_lang_foreign_SymbolLookup.createNativeLibraries(Target_java_lang_foreign_SymbolLookup.java:159)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.foreign/com.oracle.svm.core.foreign.Util_java_lang_foreign_SymbolLookup.libraryLookup(Target_java_lang_foreign_SymbolLookup.java:181)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.foreign/com.oracle.svm.core.foreign.RuntimeSystemLookup.makeSystemLookup(RuntimeSystemLookup.java:63)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.foreign/com.oracle.svm.core.foreign.RuntimeSystemLookup.<clinit>(RuntimeSystemLookup.java:39)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: libc.so.6
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibraries.loadLibraryPlatformSpecific(NativeLibraries.java:90)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.foreign/com.oracle.svm.core.foreign.Util_java_lang_foreign_SymbolLookup.createNativeLibraries(Target_java_lang_foreign_SymbolLookup.java:156)
    ... 13 more

The FFI code failing is merely this:
package testlib;

import java.lang.foreign.Arena;
import java.lang.foreign.FunctionDescriptor;
import java.lang.foreign.Linker;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SymbolLookup;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;

public class NativeBridge {
  public static long ffi() throws Throwable {
    Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
    SymbolLookup stdlib = linker.defaultLookup();
    MethodHandle strlen = linker.downcallHandle(
      stdlib.find("strlen").orElseThrow(),
      FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.ADDRESS)
    );

    try (Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
      MemorySegment cString = arena.allocateFrom("Hello");
      long len = (long)strlen.invokeExact(cString); // 5
      return len;
    }
  }
}

And the native-image command to produce the binary was this:
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/native-image \
  -jar target/testlib-kitchen-sink-0.0.1-standalone.jar \
  -cp target/testlib-kitchen-sink-0.0.1-standalone.jar \
  -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
  -H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions \
  -H:+ForeignAPISupport \
  -J-Dclojure.spec.skip.macros=true \
  -J-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true \
  --initialize-at-build-time \
  --no-fallback \
  --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime \
  --native-image-info \
  --enable-url-protocols=http,https \
  --verbose \
  -march=native \
  target/testlib-kitchen-sink-0.0.1-standalone

Environment:
❯ java -version                                                                                                                               
openjdk version "22.0.1" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu22.30+13-CA (build 22.0.1+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu22.30+13-CA (build 22.0.1+8, mixed mode, sharing)

❯ $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/native-image --version                                                                                                    
native-image 22.0.1 2024-04-16
GraalVM Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1 (build 22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01)
Substrate VM Oracle GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1 (build 22.0.1+8, serial gc, compressed references)

The FFI call runs fine when the jar is ran with java, but it fails when ran from the binary produced by native-image.
